# What's the use of pointer-casting a dereferenced pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

This question is about code explanation, not code debugging. The code I'm using works.
I'm using a public code and I was curious to look at one of their "grow array" template, which looks like this:

```
  template <typename TYPE>
    TYPE *grow(TYPE *&array, int n, const char *name)
    {
      if (array == NULL) return create(array,n,name);

      bigint nbytes = ((bigint) sizeof(TYPE)) * n;
      array = (TYPE *) srealloc(array,nbytes,name);
      return array;
    }
```

and the function **srealloc** looks like this:

```
void *Memory::srealloc(void *ptr, bigint nbytes, const char *name)
{
  if (nbytes == 0) {
    destroy(ptr);
    return NULL;
  }

  ptr = realloc(ptr,nbytes);
  if (ptr == NULL) {
error();
  }
  return ptr;
}
```

Please disregard the **create** function for now. My main question is why do they pointer-cast and dereference `array` in the template? What's the advantage of that? What if they just didn't have `*&` at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` token has many meanings, two of which you have confused here. You are not alone! As an operator, it means "address of", which you seem to be comfortable with (this comes from `C`). But as a type qualifier, it means "reference to", which is quite different. First meaning:

```
int x ;
int* p = &x ; // p = address of x (as in C)
```

Second meaning:

```
void f (int& x) { // x is a reference to an int -- its address is passed to f
  x++ ;
}
...
int y = 99 ;
f (y) ; // After this call, y is equal to 100
```

In this example, the code is equivalent to

```
void f (int* x) {
  (*x)++ ;
}
...
int y = 99 ;
f (&y) ; // After this call, y is equal to 100
```

This code doesn't look as clean, but it's easier to understand for `C` programmers.

So...the function declaration

```
void f (int*& p) ;
```

(as in your example) means that `f` can change the value of the `int*` parameter passed by the calling function. Your sample code looks a bit screwy to me, because why does it need to return the new value of `array` if it can change the parameter directly? But that is a question of style, and I have learnt not to discuss such matters here :-)

Comment: Thanks for those examples and clarification, that was very helpful. Just so I understand you correctly, could those functions have worked without a `return` since they are changing the parameter directly already?

Comment: would you mind taking a look at my comment below to @DannisZickefoose?

Answer (score 2):

```
*&
```

is not a "pointer-dereference".  It's a reference to a pointer.  It's needed so the grow function can change the pointer, rather than just what the pointer points to.  The alternative would have been a pointer to a pointer, like in the following code.

```
template <typename TYPE>
TYPE *grow(TYPE **array, int n, const char *name)
{
  if ((*array) == NULL) return create((*array),n,name);

  bigint nbytes = ((bigint) sizeof(TYPE)) * n;
  (*array) = (TYPE *) srealloc((*array),nbytes,name);
  return *array;
}
```

Comment: I understand how the alternative is identical to the current example in the question, I just don't understand why it is necessary. Why can it not be `TYPE array`, since `array` is already of type `[size] *`, where [size] is either `int`, `double`, etc.

Comment: @Amit: It looks like this is meant to re-allocate an array in place, if possible.  If it can't, it allocates a whole new array and moves everything over.  In this latter case, the original pointer ends up worthless, so updating it right away is safer.  This suggests a reference parameter.  However, memory allocation functions generally return the address of the memory they allocate.  The author probably just wanted to make sure both methods are usable; the former for safety, and the later for consistency.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose: I appreciate your comment -- that helps a lot. Thanks!!

Comment: @DennisZickefoose: If I write a similar function, but only have `TYPE array` defined, and `return array` for my `grow` function. Would it still accomplish the same functionality ?

Comment: @Amit: You mean `TYPE* array`. But yes, it would accomplish the same functionality, as long as you only call it with `array = grow (array, n, name);`

Comment: @TonyK: Indeed I meant `TYPE* array`, and thanks a lot for the helpful comments! +1